# How to identify requests made by a Flash vs. JavaScript client?

Tags: javascript, http, flash, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

On a server, is it possible to identify requests made by a Flash client running in the browser vs. requests made by a regular XMLHttpRequest?

I noticed that requests made using a flash, have this header:

```
X-Requested-With:ShockwaveFlash/25.0.0.127
```

Is this a standard header, or is this is behavior different for different browsers \ flash versions?

Comment: considering the fact that you can open a raw socket in flash, no. one can always copy the user agent / headers of the "regular" xhr and send it through the socket. how would you differentiate the requests then? even if there were a difference, who guarantees that different browsers with different version stick to that difference?

Comment: XMLHttpRequests are supposed to have a similar header `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`. These can't be relied upon as they can be spoofed, but i think the Flash header is pretty reliable in terms of general client detection.

Comment: @lofihelsinki I need to be able to differentiate flash only, so that sounds like it can cover most cases.

Comment: @DavidHaim - I don't care about cases where requests are made using sockets.
I'm only interested in "normal" behavior where requests are made using the URLRequest API.

Comment: `X-Requested-With` is not a standard HTTP header and cannot be trusted. Even in URLRequest API, `X-Requested-With` is not restricted and can be defined by end user, refer to http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestHeader.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTTP header `Referer` to check whether a request is made by Flash or JavaScript. If a request is made by Flash, then the `Referer` would be the URL of the .swf object. Thus, if the `Referer` URL contains `.swf` resource, the request must come from Flash.

According to [ActionScript 3.0 document](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestHeader.html), `Referer` is a restricted header and cannot be defined by end user. In JavaScript side, unless hacked by JS programmer, it is very unlikely to see an HTTP request whose `Referer` is `.../xxx.swf`.

For `X-Requested-With`,  it is not a standard HTTP header and cannot be trusted. Even in URLRequest API, `X-Requested-With` is not restricted and can be defined by end user, refer to [doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestHeader.html).